# Creating an ascii triangle composed of signs

Tags: python

The idea is to create a triangle, surrounded in *'s while the $ signs, spaces and height of the triangle are all user inputs.
For example, with height = 9, $=5 and spaces = 2, this should produce the following output:

```
         *
        *$*
       *$$$*
      *$ $$*
     *$$$ $$*
    *$$$ $$$$*
   *$ $$$$$ $*
  *$$$$ $$$$$ *
*****************
```

I tried a couple of different approaches, like stringing the $'s and spaces together and printing by their index, or counting how many times each was printed and not overlapping.

However, I couldn't manage to find anything that worked :(

Any help is appreciated :) just a first semester at CS

My code:

```py
    height = int(input('Enter height: '))
    numSigns = int(input('Enter number of $: '))
    numSpaces = int(input('Enter number of spaces: '))
    signCounter = 0
    spaceCounter = 0
    sign = '$'
    row = (sign*numSigns + ' '* numSpaces)*height
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    x =1
    for i in range(height):
    
        for j in range(height - i - 1):
    
            print(" ", end = '')
    
        print('*',end = '')
        if i == 0:
            print()
    
        p = x
        x = x + i - 1
        for a in range(p,x):
            print(row[a], end = '')

        if i != 0:
            print('*')
```

Actual output:

```
    Enter height: 9
    Enter number of $: 5
    Enter number of spaces: 2
            *
           **
          *$*
         *$$*
        *$$ *
       * $$$*
      *$$  $*
     *$$$$  *
    *$$$$$  *
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for help with your homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) and [ask] more generally.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see over what logic it works. You will find logic at last.

#### 1st.

How to create left-side star pattern like this :

```
    *
   *
  *
 *
```

First thing is how many spaces on the left of each star is equal to `TOTAL_HEIGHT_OF_PATTERN - CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS`. for given example let's take `2nd-line` so:

```
TOTAL_HEIGHT_OF_PATTERN = 4
CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS = 2
NUMBER_OF_SPACE_ON_LEFT = TOTAL_HEIGHT_OF_PATTERN - CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS = 2
```

#### 2nd.

How to create `$` and `space` pattern like this in between:

```
        *
       *$*
      *$$$*
     *  $$$*
    *$$$$$  *
   *$$$$$  $$*
  *$$$$$  $  $*
 *$$$    $$$$$$*
```

How many spaces at given height, for above system it is found.
spaces:0  for height @ 1, 2, 3
spaces:1  for height @ 4, 5, 6
spaces:2  for height @ 7, 8
we can see a pattern found such that at every height `(CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS-1)//3` no of space will found.
For `NO_OF_DOLLORS` we can see it equal to `2*(CURRENT_HEIGHT_STATUS-NO_OF_SPACES)-3` finally by using `shuffling operation` we can shuffle `dollor and spaces`

**Check out this code:**

```
from random import shuffle
height = int(input('Height : '))
doller = int(input('Dollor : '))
spaces = int(input('Spaces : '))

for i in range(1,height+1):
    no_spaces = (i-1)//3
    str_ = ['$' for i in range(2*(i-no_spaces)-3)]+['  ']*no_spaces
    shuffle(str_)
    if i == 1:
        print(' '*(height-i) + '*')
    elif i != height and i !=  1:
        print(' '*(height-i) + '*' + ''.join(str_) + '*')
    else:
        print('*'*(2*height-1))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Height : 9
Dollor : 2
Spaces : 5
        *
       *$*
      *$$$*
     *$$  $*
    *$$  $$$*
   *$$$$$$  $*
  *    $$$$$$$*
 *$$  $$$$$$$  *
*****************
```

Comment: honestly i expected a general idea rather than a complete code
ill do my best to follow the guidelines next time :) thanks alot for the help
this is actually fairly close to what i had but next time ill post my code with it!

edit: its my first ever post btw so sorry for being ignorant

Comment: after carefully reviewing what you wrote and messing around with it on my own for a couple of minutes it encounters the same issue i had with my code

rather than shuffling the string i need them to be in continuous order
example:
if dollors = 4 and spaces = 2
the pyramid will always have 4 followed by 2 spaces even if they are seperated by a new row
ill edit the post and share my code :D

Comment: @Flyleaf I got the point wait for few minute ill update that as I am busy now

Comment: thank you regardless and take your time :)

Comment: @Flyleaf checkout new answer I just added there

Answer (score 1):

Instead of completely using loop let's divide them in procedural code. Logic is similar to my [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67142634/14867730). For making particular `enclose-string` we can use `make_str function` who logic revolves around the remaining number of `$`

```
height = int(input('Height : '))
doller = int(input('Dollor : '))
spaces = int(input('Spaces : '))

def make_str(rem, len_str):
    x = 0
    s = ''
    for _ in range(len_str):
        if rem >0:
            s += '$'
            rem -= 1
        else:
            s += ' '
            x += 1
            if x == spaces:
                x = 0
                rem = 5
    return (rem, s)

rem_dollor = doller

for i in range(1,height+1):
    num = 2*(i)-3
    rem_dollor, str_  =  make_str(rem_dollor, num)
    if i == 1:
        print(' '*(height-i) + '*')
    elif i != height and i !=  1:
        print(' '*(height-i) + '*' + str_ + '*')
    else:
        print('*'*(2*height-1))
```

**OUTPUT: **

```
Height : 9
Dollor : 4
Spaces : 3
        *
       *$*
      *$$$*
     *   $$*
    *$$$   $*
   *$$$$   $$*
  *$$$   $$$$$*
 *   $$$$$   $$*
*****************
```